# Validate and formatting a MAC Address

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am writing a vb script that queries a wireless controller with an input box for the mac address. So you need to input something like this `98:09:cf:4b:dd:ff`.

What I want to do is allow the user to input the mac like this `9809cf3bddff` and have the script or input box code automatically add the `:` , how can I do this ?

Comment: Use a `For` loop to `Step` through 2 at a time, insert `":"`, then `Left()` the final string `Len()` - 1 to trim the last `":"`. This isn't a difficult script and likely umpteen examples on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

When you ask someone to type a MAC Address, you must check and validate it before processing another task, so for this reason i added a function that test and validate it using a Regular Expression `RegExp` before transforming it !

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,MAC_Entered
Title = "Validate MAC Address and transform it !"
Do 
    MAC_Entered = Trim(InputBox("Please enter a MAC Address for checking and validate it",Title,"9809cf3bddff"))
    If MAC_Entered = "" Then Wscript.Quit(1) 
    If IsValid(MAC_Entered) = False Then
        MsgBox DblQuote(MAC_Entered) & " is not a valid MAC Address !" & vbcrlf &_ 
        "Please re-try again !",vbExclamation,Title
    End If
Loop Until IsValid(MAC_Entered) = True

MsgBox DblQuote(MAC_Entered) & vbCrlf &_
"After Transformation" & vbCrlf &_ 
DblQuote(Transform(MAC_Entered)),vbInformation,Title

'--------------------------------------------------
Function IsValid(Entered)
    Dim RegularExpressionObject
    Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp
    With RegularExpressionObject
        .Pattern = "^(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]?){5}(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}?)$"
        If .Test(Entered)= True then
            IsValid = True
        end if
    End With
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------
Function Transform(MAC)
    Dim i,NewMAC
    If InStr(MAC,":") > 0 Then Transform = MAC : Exit Function
    If InStr(MAC,"-") > 0 Then
        NewMAC = Replace(MAC,"-",":")
        Transform = NewMAC
    Else
        For i = 1 To Len(MAC) Step 2
            NewMAC = NewMAC & Mid(MAC,i,2) & ":" 
        Next
    End If
    Transform = Left(NewMAC,Len(MAC)+(Len(MAC)\2 - 1))
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------
```